# How to save html form data in txt file using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I have a html form. I want to store form data in another txt file using javascript.
For ex: I have a html form and store-data.txt file . when user fill the form and hit submit, so data stored in store-data.txt file.
How I will do this using javascript.

Comment: There are many working examples in the web with direct links to codepen etc. Have you checked them?

Comment: https://codepen.io/Ev1ltw1n/pen/PojyaLz  Are you looking for this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript can`t save data on server. JS can save data on clients machine. Data on clients machine can be stored using [cookie](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp). But I feel, it isnt an aim. Store data from froms can server side apps, driven like php.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [filesaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) library for a clean implementation or follow along with this [codepen](https://codepen.io/amjayesh07/pen/bGBPMxx) `It is the quickest`.

Comment: Stackoverflow have snippet that make it easier to have codepen. I suggest you to include it in your question

Answer (score 0):

if you wanted to store input values assign all values in an object then `JSON.stringify` then throw it to this function to get text file of json

```
function createTextFile(str){
    var file = new Blob([str])
        anchor = document.createElement("a")
    anchor.href = URL.createObjectURL(file)
    anchor.download = "fileName"
    anchor.click()
    URL.revokeObjectURL(anchor.href)
    anchor.remove()    
}

var input = "this is a string to test"
createTextFile(input)
```

and if you wanted to save in server side with php there is function in php
[file-put-contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)